# What is the expected length of the "Slimy Slug" cellular automata

Tags: probability, random-walk, cellular-automata

A "Slimy Slug" is a simple probabilistic cellular automata defined as follows:

The Slimy Slug lives on an infinite, two-dimensional, white-coloured, square grid. For each iteration, the slug follows these rules:

1. Paint the cell the Slug is on black.
2. Look at the 4 orthogonal adjacent cells (i.e. N,E,S,W)

   - If zero of the cells are white, **Halt**.
   - If exactly one of the cells is white, move to the white cell.
   - If more than one of the cells are white, randomly move to one of the white cells. (e.g. if the white cells are N,E,W, each cell has a 1/3 probability of being the destination.)
3. Go to rule 1.

The slug will follow a random walk, and although it could theoretically continue for an infinite number of steps, it will generally halt when it traps itself. An example of a possible trail of the slug is shown below (Instead of black and white, I have false-coloured the cells with a gradient to illustrate the path of the slug). This trail has a length of 99 steps, and the slug started in the top right, and worked it's way down to the bottom left.

[image: Slimy Slug Trail]

**Is it possible to arrive at an expression for the expected length of the Slimy Slug's trail?**

This is outside my field, so I haven't had much success in researching if this is a studied problem or not. Via numerical simulation, I have arrived at a value of 70.799611 for a set of 1,000,000 runs, but I'm interested in seeing if a value can be arrived at without numerical simulation. This is motivated by a related problem in game design/educational exercise design.

Comment: In the movement rules, the second bullet point is a special-case of the third, fwiw

Comment: BAsically same question here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17438/expected-length-of-a-self-avoiding-random-walk

Comment: @AakashM - Agreed, just trying to spell it out to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: I'd search by "self avoiding random walk".

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.12680.pdf) says that the average is $70.85\pm 0.05$, but they don't have an exact value.